# How can I return the total records from my SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL

```
select year(createdat), count(id) from memberevents where memberid=22 group by year(createdat)
```

and it returns the following results

```
year(created)  count(id)
============   =========
2013            3
2014            1
```

But I want to return ONLY the recordcount of the sql so in that case it should returns

```
totalrecords
============  
2
```

But how can I do that using only one sql? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a count from a resultset by referencing the query as an inline view,

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ( your_query_here ) alias
```

for example, using the query in your question, you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM (
          select year(createdat)
               , count(id)
            from memberevents
           where memberid=22
           group by year(createdat)
       ) a
```

---

But an equivalent result could be obtained without an inline view in this case:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year(createdat))
  FROM memberevents
 WHERE memberid=22
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count the distinct number of years that match your filtering criteria.  Ne need for nested selects here.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year) FROM memberevents WHERE memberid = 22
```

Or if your intent is to run an arbitrary query and then be able to also get the row count associated with that query, You can just make a follow up call using the same connection as follows:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Note that this would not work well if you have a `LIMIT` statement as this will return all found rows, not the count of those returned after the `LIMIT` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
    YEAR(createdat) ,
    COUNT(id)
FROM memberevents
WHERE memberid = 22
GROUP BY YEAR(createdat)
) a
```